# Should an answer be a one sentence long?

Tags: discussion

In this post:

[array of pointers to class method error c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33926100/array-of-pointers-to-class-method-error-c11)

I posted one sentence as a comment instead of an answer because I feel an answer should say why you need to do it this way or why it doesn't work the way the OP tried it.  I always thought one sentence that doesn't explain anything should be a comment, but then someone posted an answer with the exact same sentence that I used.  So should I be posting my one sentence comments as answers or should an answer really explain in more detail?

Comment: Well a one sentence answer is still an answer.  But as you note, people might downvote it as not explaining enough.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about one sentence answers, the thing to look out for are one sentence questions. I have yet to see one that actually manages to cram all relevant information and context into one sentence. But the question sets the context, and so the answer no longer needs to - hence it can be quite short depending on what is asked.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Whether something is a comment or an answer has nothing to do with its length; it has to do with whether or not it answers the question.  If you can answer the question in one sentence, then it's still an answer.  If you can provide a 200 word long clarifying question, it's still not an answer.

An answer being so short is certainly a red flag that it may not be a *quality* answer.  It's typically pretty rare for an answer so short to really be a *comprehensive* answer to the question.  That wouldn't make it Not An Answer, but rather a low quality answer (possibly meriting a downvote).  Of course, while answers should *typically* contain more information, that doesn't mean that there aren't unusual cases where such a short answer really can convey all important information needed to answer a particular question.

Comment: Well, the one sentence answer has many upvotes now so you must be right.  I still think the answer should say why the parenthesis are needed or some other explanation - but in the case of that answer all that is in the comments...

Answer (score 12):

Sometimes a short answer suffices.

Comment: Proven here, upvoted.

Comment: Aww, I'm twelve minutes too slow.

Comment: @NathanTuggy FGITW! :-D