# People Managing to Type out Essay-long Answers

Tags: discussion, answers, writing-style

This is kind of an odd question, but I see all these answers to questions on Stack Overflow that are like a whole essay long, completely well-composed and well edited. For example:

[Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

My question is, do people actually spend tons of time typing out these extremely well-composed answers? Or are they often copied from books, websites, etc.?

Comment: I'd recommend leaving this question up as there's a valid question with a multifaceted answer to be had here. Don't worry about downvotes on meta.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for the recommendation man.

Comment: It is original work.  Back then SO was a major break from the way assistance was provided in forums.  It made it likely that you could explain something once and never had to do so again.  So worth the effort.

Comment: Related, if not a dupe: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351432/1079354

Comment: Interesting reading: [Another take on canonical answers: Add a “canonical” vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116087/185667)

Comment: There's almost [20 edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/613132/revisions) to the top answer on that question so feel free to check out how that answer has evolved over time.

Comment: Just an FYI, I _did_ VTC, but only because the question lends itself to opinion-based answers. The answers so far are absolutely not.

Comment: Actually writing a long essay is often simpler as to formulate the same in a concentrated form.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are indeed a good number of people, myself included, who have the time and will invest said time, and effort, into writing very thorough and comprehensive answers. Some of the most prolific answerers on Stack Overflow produce above-average-quality answers pretty much year-round. Yes, this does demand quite a lot of your spare time. Sometimes it takes the better part of an hour; other times it can take several days. It depends on the subject matter, how much the author knows, and how much depth they're willing to go into as they deem fit for the question.

And speaking of investing, I made a Data Explorer query some time ago to see [how well my longest answers fared over time](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/619016/how-well-do-my-lengthy-detail-rich-answers-perform-over-time?UserId=106224) — the ROI can actually vary pretty greatly as you'll find that my second longest answer has had nearly two orders of magnitude more traffic and votes than my longest, while being only half its length (but still pretty long at 9875 and 17,568 characters respectively). That said, I'm equally proud of every one of them. I think they're all some of my best pieces of technical writing.

Having said that, there are also cases of users copying content from books, websites, etc, but you'll find that these are relatively rare depending on the tags you participate in. (Well I guess encyclopedic answers that are *original* are just as rare, but my point is they're all pretty uncommon.) Generally, most answers that are copied from elsewhere

- aren't formatted very well — plagiarists often don't put much thought into making their answers look good. They'll just dump the content straight out of their clipboard and call it a day. If they make any edits at all, they're almost never going to bother making enough to make the answer look "complete". You'll spot these types of answers from a mile away, and when you do it's simply a matter of flagging the stolen content for moderator attention (and leaving a comment to that effect).
- aren't tailored to the question — some questions are just broad enough to not require an entire book to answer, but still benefit from a deep dive. But an ideal answer relates as much to the question as possible without making too many assumptions, while still making the right ones. Depending on the scope of the question and the answer, at best a copied answer partially addresses the question; at worst, not at all. An answer copying from W3Schools or from some general-knowledge article isn't going to address all but the most trivial of questions, for example.

You've tagged your discussion [writing-style](/questions/tagged/writing-style); writing style is also a pretty good indicator if an answer is really someone's original writing, or if it's not their own. A lot of copied content stems from users who don't write well (or at least don't think they do). If they start producing comments in broken English, or sound like they have no idea what they just "wrote", chances are their well-written answer or answer that's written in a completely different flavor of English wasn't written by them at all. This may also be an indication that they didn't mean to *steal* the content, but it counts as plagiarism and a violation of the attribution rules all the same (and if they start reverting attempts to add attribution it's pretty safe to say they're no longer acting in good faith).

You're not required or even expected to match the quality and comprehensiveness of these types of answers. Not by a long stretch. It's just an added bonus from those who are dedicated enough and want to share extensive amounts of knowledge beyond what is required of the question. As long as you produce answers that are accurate, useful, and backed up by references as needed, sometimes even a single quote of a single sentence that explains how a certain feature works is enough, if said feature really is that simple.

Comment: Some people invest a lot of time and write a long answer. Some people invest even **more** time and write a **short** one ;-)

Comment: @Marco13: Yes, but we really do want comprehensive answers.

Comment: @PeterMortensen It's an art to hit the right spot between a "piece of information that can only be understood by someone who wouldn't have asked the question in the first place", and an "essay that explains computer programming, mentioning that in the beginning the earth was `void`" (because keywords have to be `backticked`). It strongly depends on the type of question, that's for sure. Sometimes, a few lines of code are worth *more* than a thousand words...

Comment: Nice answer, and lovely query. @Marco13 : That's a good point. One of the things that took me the longest to learn was when not to throw the kitchen sink at it.

Comment: @Marco13: That hasn't been my experience. Aside from time spent on research (because it varies too much to be measurable), the time I take to write an answer is usually directly proportional to the length of the answer - mostly because I don't take a long answer and spend the same amount of time I took to write it cutting it down to size afterward. That's just inefficient.

Comment: The first comment roughly referred to the famous [shorter letter quote](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2012/04/28/shorter-letter/). It's clear that one *can* go too far and make an answer too long or "too comprehensive". Some may just hit it, and write down the answer with *just* the right level of detail, whereas others may have to do a "cleanup pass" afterwards. And of course, a short answer is not necessarily bad, and a long answer not necessarily good. But there's likely no point in arguing about this in general (and maybe not even for a *specific* answer - it's a matter of opinions).

Answer (score 7):

> My question is, do people actually spend tons of time typing out these extremely well-composed answers?

Yes.

<sup>(I considered to end my answer here, just for the absurdity, but ...)</sup>

It certainly depends on many factors, and one could argue about whether an answer should be an essay, or whether [an answer should only be one sentence long](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311164/3182664). In the worst case, an elaborate answer is long simply because it fails to come to the point. Conversely, one could say that when a long answer is *necessary*, then the question should be closed as "Too Broad".

The specific answer that you linked to contains a comment from the author, saying that the answer originally was a FAQ entry. And indeed, sometimes FAQ- or tutorial pages are basically migrated to stack overflow, either because of the visibility or the durability of the site, or because each FAQ is also frequently asked here, and if it fits, it sits.

But there certainly are cases where a question is either very broad or justifies a detailed explanation of some underlying concepts. And in these cases, people who are interested in the topic or have accumulated some knowledge that they want to share do this by writing an answer that goes beyond what would be the "shortest reasonable answer" for a question.

---

<sub>(Using the query from the [answer by BoltClock♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/376491/3182664) to search for [my longest answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/619016/how-well-do-my-lengthy-detail-rich-answers-perform-over-time?UserId=3182664) shows that they are in many cases rather long because I posted [MCVEs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This is another option for investing time and effort into an answer, even though it then is not necessarily an "essay". One exception here is an [answer to the question about Java and CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22868938/3182664), where I summarized some knowledge that I accumulated up to this point and that I thought could be helpful for people stumbling over this question, even though I may have overshoot the target with that one...)</sub>

Answer (score 7):

I have often typed long answers in the form of a tutorial. When I see someone who clearly is having trouble grasping some element of what is going on, rather than see the question closed, I have composed a longer answer that would hopefully help others who are in the same position. I am in a position to often see, and work with beginners who demonstrate the same level of confusion and I can bring my experience to these answers.

I choose questions that have been passed and not answered by others, who I know could write an answer, but think it not worthwhile, often because the question could  be considered poor.

I have received comments saying they are great answers to rotten questions!

Answer (score 6):

[BoltClock's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/376491/2751851) already covers the general issues, so I, [like Brian Tompsett](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/376495/2751851), will talk a bit about things that can lead me to write unusually long answers. There are two main factors I can think of:

- Sometimes there is a really interesting issue lying just below the surface of what appears to be a simple beginner question. I enjoy writing longer answers that bring such issues into light. I feel especially motivated to do so when the OP themselves show some intuition about what is at stake, even if they don't (yet) have enough familiarity with the relevant concepts and vocabulary to articulate it clearly. It is worth noting [Marco13's very valid point](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376489/people-managing-to-type-out-essay-long-answers#comment645860_376491) that it is a delicate art to figure out when to write such answers, and how far to go when doing so -- it is not difficult to get carried away and write something that doesn't give enough attention to the immediate issue in the question, is unintelligible for the OP, or is so meandering that readers end up losing interest. Writing a lot and paying attention to feedback is probably the only way to learn that.
- Other times, an interesting or tricky question happens to be about something I want to learn more about, and so the question works as a springboard for my own studying. Such situations lend themselves to detailed answers, in which I try to incorporate as much of what I have learned as I can manage without drifting off-topic. For a related point of view, have a look at [this very interesting answer by Yakk](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315041/2751851) elsewhere on Meta.